# Keyboard shortcut for "save image as"

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Does such a shortcut exist?

I understand that since there will most likely be multiples images on a webpage, you have to physically have your mouse over the image you want to save and then right click (Windows 7) on the image and then select "save image as" but is there a keyboard shortcut to this process?

Comment: Just to be clear in case my question was not clear. When i hover my mouse cursor over an image I'm wondering if there is a shortcut for the process of right clicking "save image as". I understand the mouse cursor has to be over the image I intend to save but is there a shortcut for that process.

Answer (score 5):

Your browser can't guess what image you want to download just by using a shortcut, some broswer extensions could do the trick by showing you all of the images on the page and letting you select which one you want to download, and you'd still have to select one. But if you have already opened the image on a page, and only the image, you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save it.

Answer (score 5):

there's a few options here

1. Either bulk download the url on all images (http://www.webimagedownloader.com/) works well
2. Right click image → Press "V" , asks where you want to save it

if you want to automate it this way I would use a macro and do following:

1. Hover over image
2. Press hotkey (triggers Right click mouse, "V", and "enter")

Comment: although i love all the supplemental links people posted, #2 is the actual answer for the question, some may say a right click isn't a keyboard shortcut and [ shift+F10 ] the hotkey for rightclick isn't context specific, but this is probably as close as it gets. Still save time. Alternatively, you could press [ right-click + down + down ] or figure out a mouse keys way of doing it.

Comment: thanks, this really helped me. How would I record a macro (in chrome)?

Comment: @Nova I've created a chrome extension that does the job, I hope it saves your time even more (Check my answer below) :)

Answer (score 2):

**I have created a chrome extension that does exactly what you asked for:** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-handling-shortcuts/dhnacegooljnejkdlpepjgklfmphpikg/related?hl=en-GB&authuser=0

#### How to use

Basically, put your cursor on the images and use the shortcut `ctrl + shift + s` to save image as, or use `ctrl + shift + c` to copy the image address

*[Watch this video for more info](https://youtu.be/EZYbMqCBUSU)*

If you think the shortcut isn't good and needs to be changed, or want me to add any new shortcuts please leave a comment here or open an issue on the Github page [Here](https://github.com/zeyad-shaban/image-handling-shortcuts/issues)

*If you found it helpful please don't forget to upvote the answer and rate the extension, Thanks*

Comment: Thanks Zeyad! This works for one-offs, I was here actually looking for a method that opens all thumbnails on a page and saves the full resolution pictures. Still haven't found a method to do that, including the suggestion above

Comment: @Nova really sorry that the extension didn't do what you wanted :( But I hope it's somehow usefull

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what behavior do you expect. As correctly noted by arielnmz, browser will have no idea which image do you want to save. So it is impractical to have a shortcut like this. Options that you have is to use an extension-based or external download manager that will provide you additional interface for downloading images. I remember, there there used to be one called DownloadThemAll for Firefox, it did the job pretty well for me, allowing to download all pictures from the web page in two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need at least 2 third-party software, one to recognize the position of the pointer on the current active window, and a second that can generate a shortcut for the action that you want, but remember that a lot of webpages nowadays use a 'transperent' image overlay that covers the real image, so the users won't be able to 'save' the images, so if the user 'saves' a image, what they're saving actually is just a transparent image, generally a 16*16 square; if you got this issue, try saving the page using good 'ol > CRTL+S, then check the saved webpage folder, there should be your desired image

this is not a 'so-elegant' way to do it, but sometimes is easier to do this than a go for a more complicated approach